# Run Android RPI on Android emulator

Tags: rom-flashing, android-emulator, aosp

I want to run the compiled images of the Android RPI 3 on an Android emulator. I have looked everywhere but I didn't find any way to emulate Raspberry PI and sideload the images.

Is it possible to run Raspberry PI Android image on an emulator or any image of another hardware on an emulator?

Comment: Given that emulator is supposed to 'emulate' a AOSP device, what do you mean by `I want to run the Compiled images of the Android RPI 3` as there are no HAT or other specialized third part hardware to connect.

Comment: What i want to do is to run the compiled Images of RPI3 into android Emulator, how to costumize AVD to run customized rom of a device ?

Answer (score 0):

The Android Emulator uses [QEMU](https://www.qemu.org/) as the [hypervisor](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline#filedir).

While QEMU appears to emulate [Raspberry Pi 2](https://wiki.qemu.org/Documentation/Platforms/ARM) you should read the documentation about [ARM support](https://qemu.weilnetz.de/doc/qemu-doc.html#ARM-System-emulator) to see if it fits your needs.

**Update**

Physical devices have different driver configuration than the emulator.

And if you want emulator to have any performance you'll have to use a different CPU architecture (x86 vs ARM). Please reach up on [Adding a New Device](https://source.android.com/setup/develop/new-device) in the AOSP documentation (note the layers).

I don't know if you could run a binary AOSP image on RPi on QEMU but it would be slow (and still need to configure fastboot etc.), this thread: https://www.raspberrypi.org/magpi/android-raspberry-pi/ leads me to believe that drivers will be the blocking point.

Another thing that is leading me to say what you want is **very difficult** is that it sounds like you want load almost arbitrary images. This article on XDA about [EFIDroid](https://www.xda-developers.com/efidroid-is-a-second-stage-bootloader/) shows what I think you want but is limited to a set of supported Qualcomm Snapdragon devices.

Comment: Here is basically what i am interested in, i want to customize QEMU or anrdoid emulator to run any other custom Rom ( system image, ramdisk, kernel...) not necessarily RPI3 but run any other images that i compile using AOSP

Comment: If you are already building new AOSP image what is wrong with [Running emulator after building Android from source](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9022750/295004) in which case this question is getting off-topic for **Android Enthusiasts**

Comment: i guess i haven't explain my needs very well, the question is basicaly, can i run different images and also load emulator with kernel different than goldfish for testing purpose. for example running LineageOS or other custom rom on the Emulator before flash it in your physical device

Comment: I've updated my answer, I'm leaning toward **very difficult** as you give the examples of (a) a different kernel (b) a different OS. *If you want off the shelf solution, I don't believe there is one.*

Comment: Ok, i have been looking around the the only thing i found is this which is very old: https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1599005 , that's basically what i want to do or at least be able to do with different device ROM. in the XDA post they load SDK add-on of the Xperia X10 and then use it to load Xperia image and run it on emulator.

Comment: I believe it is using the ARM version of the emulator to run your 'image' so back in the Android 2.x days the hardware layout/kernel may have been similar enough.

Comment: OK i understand, i will keep looking around maybe i will find another solution.What about building an android emulator based on QEMU source code from the ground up and you can add support for your device ? is that something possible ?